# jQuery hide show div doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

When I click `togglediv`, **`commentdiv`** must be visible or hidden. The following code is running on Firefox but not Internet Explorer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#togglediv").click(function(){ 
        if( $("#commentdiv").is(":visible") ) {
            $("#commentdiv").hide("slow");
            $("#togglediv").text("show");
        } else {
            $("#commentdiv").show("slow");
            $("#togglediv").text("hide");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#togglediv").click(function() {
    // note: do this first because the :hidden test fails if you
    // do it after triggering a slow animation
    $("#togglediv").text($("#commentdiv").is(":hidden") ? "Hide" : "Sgiw");
    $("#commentdiv").toggle('slow');
  });
});
```

**Edit:** In response to your comment, this example works perfectly for me in IE7/FF3.  **Note:** I did have to reverse the order of statements when using slow effects.  Interesting!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #togglediv { padding: 5px; background-color: yellow; }
    #commentdiv { padding: 5px; background-color: #CCC; height: 100px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="togglediv">Hide</div>
  <div id="commentdiv">thanks for answer. but i have tried this code, it was okay. i want to use toggle("slow") effect. this effect is runing firefox, but not i.e. is it a bug?</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#togglediv").click(function() {
      $("#togglediv").text($("#commentdiv").is(":hidden") ? "Hide" : "Show");
      $("#commentdiv").toggle('slow');
    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but i have tried this code, it was okay. i want to use toggle("slow") effect. this effect is runing firefox, but not i.e. is it a bug?

Answer (score 6):

There is a function **toggle** in jquery that does exactly what you want without having to check for visibility:

```
$("#commentdiv").toggle("slow");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing }

Try

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#togglediv").click(function(){
                if($("#commentdiv").is(":visible")){
                $("#commentdiv").hide("slow"); $("#togglediv").text("show");
                }
                else{
                $("#commentdiv").show("slow"); $("#togglediv").text("hide");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Something I noticed that was interesting, and I think it was touched on above by cletus, is that if you switch the order of the "show" line with the "text" line - it seems to start working. I have no explanation for this; it would be nice to know what is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(document.getElementById(ThisObj).style.display == 'none')
{
    document.getElementById(ThisObj).style.display = 'block';
}
else
{
    document.getElementById(ThisObj).style.display = 'none';
}
```

it works:)