# JQUERY; show/hide isnt firing in IE, works on other browsers

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, hide, show

okay below is part of the code im using for this site. its supposed to be where you click on the image and it "shows" a div that was hidden before. Then when you click another picture it hides the currently opened div and shows the new one. it works in every browser except IE (of course.) and im not sure what i did wrong with script, help please?

```
<div class="content">
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
  <td align="center">
    <a id="1" href="#"><img src="..." width="100" height="92" alt="1" /></a>
    <a id="2" href="#"><img src="..." width="100" height="70" alt="2" /></a>
    <a id="3" href="#"><img src="..." width="100" height="112" alt="3" /></a>
    <a id="4" href="#"><img src="..." width="100" height="65" alt="4" /></a> 
    <a id="5" href="#"><img src="..." width="100" height="141" alt="5" /></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="frame1">
  <button>close</button>
  <iframe src="..." width="100%" height="100%">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</div>
<div id="frame2">
  <button>close</button>
  <iframe src="..." width="100%" height="100%">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
  </iframe>
</div>
<div id="frame3">
  <button>close</button>
  <iframe src="..." width="100%" height="100%">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</div>
```

etc...

```
<script>
//controller for first site
$("a#1").click(function () {
    $("#frame2,#frame3,#frame4,#frame5").hide("fast");
    $("#frame1").show("slow");
});
//controller for second site
$("a#2").click(function () {
    $("#frame1,#frame3,#frame4,#frame5").hide("fast");
    $("#frame2").show("slow");
});
//controller for third site
$("a#3").click(function () {
    $("#frame1,#frame2,#frame4,#frame5").hide("fast");
    $("#frame3").show("slow");
});
//controller for fourth site
$("a#4").click(function () {
    $("#frame1,#frame2,#frame3,#frame5").hide("fast");
    $("#frame4").show("slow");
});
//controller for fifth site
$("a#5").click(function () {
    $("#frame1,#frame2,#frame3,#frame4").hide("fast");
    $("#frame5").show("slow");
});
//button close frames
$("button").click(function () {
    $("#frame1,#frame2,#frame3,#frame4,#frame5").hide("fast");
});
</script>
```

and of course the css of the frame divs had to be "display:none;" for it to work.

Comment: no, there was no errors that popped up in dreamweaver.

Comment: Have you used Jquery accordian?

Comment: yes i have, i dont really wanna do it like that though.

Comment: you should really be using classes instead of such a long list of IDs

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/km6m2/ - it works in IE for me?

Comment: thats weird, it always does this to me lol

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a#1").click(function () {
    $('div[id~="frame"]').css({"display":"none"}); //hides all divs with id containing "frame"
    $("#frame1").show("slow");
  });
});
```

Note: Your  is not a good practice.

> The ID and NAME elements must start
>   with a letter i.e. upper case A to Z
>   or lower case a to z; a number is not
>   allowed. After the first letter any
>   number of letters (a to z, A to Z),
>   digits (0 to 9), hyphens (-),
>   underscores (_), colons (:) and
>   periods (.) are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having similar problem... Hiding ALL and then showing one fixed the problem for me...
so just give a try with

```
//controller for first site
$("a#1").click(function () {
    $("#frame1,#frame2,#frame3,#frame4,#frame5").hide("fast");
    $("#frame1").show("slow");
});
```

and try to use other identifier then enumeration

Comment: @user645607 try to look at similar [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513735/jquery-hide-show-div-problem-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Have you put your jQuery code in a [document ready block](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready)?
Kind of like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a#1").click(function () {
    $("#frame2,#frame3,#frame4,#frame5").hide("fast");
    $("#frame1").show("slow");
});
});
```

I had that problem aswell when Firefox was able to load my javascript files before executing. IE had a bit more problems with that.

**Edit:** try using a textual ID for your links.
e.g:

```
<a id="link1" href="...">link text</a>
```

ID's aren't meant to start with numbers, so IE could give problems on this.

Comment: AH i cant believe i forgot that. But it still didn't work when i fixed it.

Comment: Have you checked if the "click" block is even reached? By simply putting a 'alert()' function in it? This could help determine if it's your "a#1" expression failing, or the hide() function failing

Answer (score 0):

Just give a try with following code, but not sure,

```
$("a#1").live('click', function(event) {//hide and show}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try giving your links ID values that don't start with numbers. [Numbers aren't valid to start out ID and NAME attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html), but they *can* be used after the initial character.

Also, may I suggest that you write out your code something like:

```
$('div.content a[href="#"]').click(function(){
    // I'm assuming that you'll be changing the ID of the link,
    // so we'll use the IMG instead
    var num = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');

    $('iframe').not('#iframe'+num).hide('fast')
               .end().filter('#iframe'+num).show('slow');
});
```

This way, you only have this small chunk of code that takes care of all that repeated code that handles the `IFRAME` show/hide behavior. Just tweak it as you would please.

Comment: that's a little complicated for me to use lol im kinda new to jquery. and thanks ill try it.

Comment: Don't worry, that's just a suggestion from me. I think your bigger problem is that you're using ID values that start with numbers --- do something about that first. :D