# jquery show() with parameter not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, show

I use jQuery, .Net and IE8 as browser.

```
$(".someClass").show();
```

works well, but not

```
$(".someClass").show("slow");
```

or

```
$(".someClass").show(1000);
```

There is no reaction at all.

Comment: See this question and answer, might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513735/jquery-hide-show-div-problem-internet-explorer

Comment: Please give a hint how and where

Comment: Sample code at http://jsbin.com/itugo5/3/ using .show('slow') works as expected in IE8. I think your problem is rooted somewhere else.

Comment: thanks, you are right, solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn´t provide enough info - actually I tried to show a `<td>`-Tag slowly, which doesn´t work. Only show() works in connection with td´s I think.