# jQuery show/hide does not work on IE

Tags: jquery, show, show-hide

I have made simple jQuery script that should show div element when hovering mouse over another div (image).

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#slider").hover(function(){
        jQuery("#slider .hovercontent").fadeTo('fast', 1);
    },function(){
        jQuery('#slider .hovercontent').fadeTo('slow', 0);
    });
});
```

This works flawless on FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera but when using IE8 or 9 image in `#slider` div disappear. What is wrong? Tried to search answer for this but no luck.
Thanks.

Comment: Works fine in my IE9. Have not tried in IE8...

Comment: Did you find this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513735/jquery-hide-show-div-problem-internet-explorer

It might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try fadein and fadeout or show and hide instead of fadeTo.